# What is arduino_debug.exe for IDE 1.5.6r2?

Tags: arduino-ide

After installing IDE 1.5.6r2, there are two .exe files, **arduino_debug**.exe and **arduino**.exe (which is same name as previously installed IDE 1.0.5).

Comment: Pretty sure it's the debug build...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows binaries can either be Window or Console applications. A Window application can NOT produce text output. Text output is the easiest way to gather error messages related to bugs.

Hence, `arduino_debug.exe` should be used by Windows users that have found a bug in the Arduino IDE and wish to contribute submitting an [issue on github](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues).